# Why VSCode unable to immediately update the file checksums?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension to modify the background, this operation requires modifying the source CSS file for vscode, Therefore, after I make the changes, vscoe pops up a warning that says "Your Code installation appears to be corrupt".

After a period of research, I decided to refresh the file checksums of the source file. The process went smoothly and I was able to refresh the checksums after modifying the CSS file. However, after I modified the CSS file and checksums, and used `vscode.window.executeCommand('workbench.action.reloadWindow')` to reload the window, the warning still appeared. Only when I manually closed vscode and opened it again would this warning disappear.

I'm very puzzled by this behavior. Does the checksum verification request data from the server? However, this warning also appears in offline mode. Or does vscode not clear the cache when restarted using built-in commands, causing the detected data to remain unchanged?

I attempted to use Node.js to directly close the application, but this did not accomplish a restart.

What apporach should I use to resolve this issue?